# How to store pure HTML in Eloquent database

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

I'm building an admin panel and Im using WYSIWYG editor which converts images to base64 code.

When I try to save that field in Eloquent's database it's escaping the malicious code.  How can I stop that being used for that field ?!

My code so far..

```
        $article_data = new Article;

    $article_data->title = $request->input('title');
    $article_data->text = $request->input('text');
    $article_data->moderator_id = $request->session()->get('moderator_id');

    $article_data->save();
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but as far as I know there should be no stage in the Laravel stack where input data is escaped. What is your server setup? Is it possible that it has magic quotes enabled?

Comment: Alerady fixed... The problem was that the text field store only 64kb data , now changed to mediumtext 16MB :)

Comment: Good to hear:) Just for the record I would say that the data was pruned then, rather than escaped.